# SQL Server PDO error: There are no more rows in the active result set. Since this result set is not scrollable, no more data may be retrieved

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

estou tetando pegar registros de uma tabela e gravar em outra do mesmo tipo, mas estou tendo este erro:

> There are no more rows in the active result set. Since this result set is not scrollable, no more data may be retrieved.

o código é o seguinte

```
 $gameuser = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM [omegashop].[dbo].[GameUser] WHERE [token] = :token');
  $gameuser->bindParam(':token', $token, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $gameuser->execute();

  $result = $gameuser->fetchAll();
  foreach($result as $linha)
  {
      $usuario = $linha['userid'];
      $senha   = $linha['Passwd'];
      $remote  = 0;

      $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO [accountdb].[dbo].[".( strtoupper($usuario[0]) ) ."GameUser] ([userid],[Passwd],[GPCode],[RegistDay],[DisuseDay],[inuse],[Grade],[EventChk],[SelectChk],[BlockChk],[SpecialChk],[Credit],[DelChk],[Channel]) values( :usuario, :senha,'PTP-RUD001','12-12-2020','12-12-2020','0','U','0','0','0','0','0','0', :remote)");
      $query->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->bindParam(':senha', $senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->bindParam(':remote', $remote, PDO::PARAM_STR);

      $query->execute();
  }`
```

Comment: Coloca um `$query->closeCursor();` depois do `$query->execute();`

Comment: agora estou recebendo isso The statement must be executed before results can be retrieved.@edit opa diz o inverso vou tentar novamente

Comment: ainda continua o erro

Comment: entendi a logica desse método, agora consegui, obrigado. poderia postar a resposta descrevendo este método?

Comment: Adiciona a instanciação do seu objeto $pdo acredito ser algumas coisa na sua  pré-configuração mas sem esse detalhe não há como ter certeza.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma de resolver isso é informar ao servidor que a consulta/comando terminou não sendo necessário nenhum tipo de sincronização. Chame o método [closeCursor()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php) depois do `execute()`

Seu código deve ficar:

```
$query->execute();
$query->closeCursor();
```